# Why automatic newline not working on CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, newline, line-breaks

I checked all the files searching extra spaces before and after `<?php` or `?>` tags without results.
Someone knows why Codeigniter is outputing HTML code without the newline?

For example:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('/login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('email', '', 'id="email" placeholder="Email"');
    echo form_password('password', '', 'id="password" placeholder="password"');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'login');
    echo anchor('/login/signup', 'sign up');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

I expect:

```
<form action="http://localhost/login/validate_credentials" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" placeholder="password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login"  />
<a href="http://localhost/login/signup">sign up</a>
</form>
```

But i get:

```
<form action="http://localhost/login/validate_credentials" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" placeholder="Email" /><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion"  /><a href="http://localhost/login/registro">Crear Cuenta</a></form>
```

This is not only happening with form helper, for example i am using Facebook Connect and when i do `var_dump($fb_data)` i get:

```
array(2) { ["me"]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(17) "101654498872" ["email"]=> string(20) "example@gmail.com" ["first_name"]=> string(8) "My Name" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["last_name"]=> string(6)...... bla bla bla more code
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: will add when you add manually?

Comment: You mean if i add manually html? yes, works perfect. The problem is when i use php with codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding newlines... Try the following:

```
<?php echo form_open('/login/validate_credentials'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('email', '', 'id="email" placeholder="Email"'); ?>
<?php echo form_password('password', '', 'id="password" placeholder="password"'); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'login'); ?>
<?php echo anchor('/login/signup', 'sign up'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

For the var_dump(), use the following method to echo it:

```
<?php echo print_r(var_dump($variable),true); ?>
```

And in a browser, use the following for 'pretty print':

```
<pre><?php echo print_r(var_dump($variable),true); ?></pre>
```

Comment: If i am not wrong CodeIgniter add automatic newlines in form helper functions. But for testing i tried your code and is not working. I really don't know what to do...

Comment: In which file are you trying this? Controller, view, model?

Comment: the form code in a view, the var_dump() in a controller

Comment: Hey, i tried with pre tags and works, sorry that i didn't test it yesterday. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to echo an html tag like `<br/>` i always use this to create newline

```
<?php
    echo form_open('/login/validate_credentials');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_input('email', '', 'id="email" placeholder="Email"');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_password('password', '', 'id="password" placeholder="password"');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_submit('submit', 'login');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo anchor('/login/signup', 'sign up');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: Yes i know and i have the br() function too in CodeIgniter, but as far as i know the br is automatic in this case and i don't know why is not working. By the way, i can solve the form thing but what can i do with var_dump(data)? the output is not indent and without newlines.